# Git isn't using the right ssh key but ssh -T is correct

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have multiple ssh key for different GitHub account and git doesn't seem to be using the right one.

.ssh/config

```
#work repo
Host git-work
     HostName github.com
     User git
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     Identityfile ~/.ssh/work

#perso repo
Host git-personal
     HostName github.com
     User git
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     Identityfile ~/.ssh/personal
```

and

```
ssh -T git-work
Hi Work! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

```
ssh -T git-personal
Hi personal! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I cloned the repo using `git clone git-work:foo/bar.git` but when I commit and then push it's my personal account who pushed the commit and not my work account.

I checked that both keys where added to ssh-agent and both account have the right sshKey.pub set up (and they are different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the push succeeds, that means the work account was used for authentication.

This has nothing to do with commit authorship (`git config user.name`/`user.email`), which is what you see when browsing the log history of the remote repository.

Check first that the `user.name`/`email` is properly set in each repository.